# Rails: Many-to-many relationships with 3 Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a situation where I have **Products**, **Suppliers**, **ShoppingLists** and **Valuations**.

A **shopping_list** consist of many **valuations** each with a **product**, an specific **supplier** and a *price*.

My models are as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valuations
  has_many :shopping_lists, :through => :valuations
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valuations
  has_many :shopping_lists, :through => :valuations
end

class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :valuations
  has_many :products, :through => :valuations
  has_many :suppliers, :through => :valuations
end

class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :shopping_list
end
```

My **routes.rb** is:

```
  map.resources :shopping_lists do |shopping_list|
    shopping_list.resources :valuations
  end

  map.resources :product

  map.resources :supplier
```

*I wonder if this could be the best solution*, anyway what I want is that the user can create as many lists as he wish, each with several valuations.

The first time a shopping list is created its also filled with **one valuation at least**. Then, the user can add/remove valuations to/from the shopping_list.

I would like a simple and elegant solution, without Ajax callbacks.

What is the best way to do this, from the **controllers/views/routes** perspectives?
Or should I completley change my schema ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found two excelent resources from Ryan Bates:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Let's see if that do the job!

// UPDATE: Worked great!